# Randomly drawing an element from a collection with varied probabilities

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, random, data-structures

Let's say I have a bag with 10 marbles: 5 red, 3 green and 2 blue. I want to randomly draw one marble.

I need to do it in Node.js and considered simple array of objects like:

```js
[
    { color: "red", score: 5},
    { color: "green", score: 3},
    { color: "blue", score: 2}
]
```

then rolling a number and iterating through the array until running score total would be greater than rolled number.

Still, perhaps this simple algorithm could use some refinement (perhaps sorting the array ahead of drawing?), replacing entirely with better one or there is some better data structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "rolling a number"?

Comment: Generate random integer in range <1, scoreTotal>. In this example it would be <1, 10>. Let's say we rolled 7, then the result will be green marble as red's running total is 5 < 7 and green's running total is 5+3 > 7.

Comment: Where is `5` derived from at "green's running total is 5+3 > 7"? What issue are you having implementing the algorithm?

Comment: By "score running total" I mean accumulated value of score as of given iteration. We iterate from the beginning of the array. First, there is { color: "red", score: 5} so "red" has running total of 5, then { color: "green", score: 3} so "green" has running total of 8 as it accumulated 5 from "red" and 3 from its own score. My issue is I'm afraid it's suboptimal solution so I ask for better one.

Comment: @Forseti In the worst case, your algorithm will look at each color's "weight" once. An optimal algorithm must also look at each color's "weight" once in the worst case (except for the last color's, but that's true of your algorithm as well). The worst-case time complexity of this algorithm is therefore optimal for the problem to solve. You might find a more elegant solution but you will not find a faster one.

Comment: Not  gathering requirement.